# Delete for std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm dynamically creating threads:

```
auto thr =new std::future<void>(std::async(/*some callable*/));
```

I'm storing all of these pointers in a `std::vector<future<void>*>`. For freeing up memory I'm doing like:

```
for(int i(0);i<futureVector.size();i++)
{
    if(futureVector.at(i)->valid())
    {
        futureVector.at(i)->get();  // for getting exception,if any
    }
    delete futureVector.at(i);    // the problem is here
}
```

Now in my code it may happen that the memory allocated for `futureVector.at(i)` is already freed (maybe in some other thread, may beby some other function).
My question is how I can detect the pointer at `futureVector.at(i)` is valid or not? I'mean it points to a valid `std::future` or not?

Note: the `futureVector` variable is static member of my class.

---

Say if I don't delete that `future` object is the cost very large ( already retrieved future)

Comment: Of course the question is, why do you store pointers... ? Oh, and if several threads may access this vector, you'll need synchronization.

Comment: Because I've no idea how many threads i need to create.... and yes I've used std::mutex for synchronization

Comment: This is not a good answer, actually. You could be using `std::vector<std::future<void>>` without knowing how many threads you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If for some reason you actually need pointers you should not use owning raw pointers in your vector.

```
auto thr = std::make_unique<std::future<void>>(std::async(/*some callable*/)); // C++14

std::unique_ptr<std::future<void>> thr {new auto {std::async(/*some callable*/)}; // C++11
```

But really you probably don't need pointers at all. Just because you don't know how many threads you'll create doesn't mean you need to use pointers.

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> futureVector;
futureVector.emplace_back(std::async(/*some callable*/));
```

Either way you don't need to loop through manually and delete anything.

> (maybe in some other thread, may beby some other function)

If you still go for raw pointers then you really need to define the ownership policy better than that. Allowing some random other bit of code to delete resources it doesn't own is not a good idea.

Comment: For curiosity: Is there any way to achieve the second way without c++11 (for other object, not std::future), not necessarily in this perticular case. I mean to achieve the same functionality as vector::emplace_back()

Comment: `emplace_back` relies on move semantics to avoid a copy. Pre-C++11 you can just go ahead and use `push_back` and the results will be the same except with an extra copy (although the object then will need to be copyable).